# linux g++ x64 access memory via FS segment register

Tags: assembly, g++, 64-bit, x86-64

Using g++ on linux, amd64, I know thread local storage is accessed via segment register GS . 
I would like to have a way to instruct the compiler to access some other memory via the FS register.
That memory is a garbage collected zone that I want to switch at will with other banks.
Is it possible to do it ? ( I suppose it should be because it is possible for thread local storage).

Comment: Actually, gs is i386, TLS fs is x86_64 (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html), but I assume the question remains the same, but then for gs. If possible, I assume there would be some FAR attribute to attach to this variable,. but I haven't been able to find it. It exists for djgpp though, for access to opengl framebuffer and dos space.

Comment: It is a hint, I will investigate the far attribute.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you're allowed to load FS or GS from user-mode. Or are you not intending on doing that?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes I want to do that. Why do you say that I should not be allowed to load FS or GS from user mode ( I don't know - is that a privileged instruction ? )

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I checked the LFS LGS instructions, and these act normally (in protected mode) loading the selector into the register FS or GS and automatically loading from the LDT (local descriptor table) the associated segment descriptor in the hidden part of the segment register. Moreover also the pop instruction may be used for the same scope. Obviously in order to have the whole to work, you must also load the local descriptor table with the necessary address ( I tried to use the system call "modify_ldt" ).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer that I will explore is the Clang

http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

"Annotating a pointer with address space #256 causes it to be code generated relative to the X86 GS segment register, and address space #257 causes it to be relative to the X86 FS segment. Note that this is a very very low-level feature that should only be used if you know what you’re doing (for example in an OS kernel)."